# Using multiple views folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I know `config/view.php` accepts multiple view paths, but it seems it doesn't solve my problem, which is the following:

I want to have a folder structure like this:

```
resources
-- admin
----- views
-------- layout.blade.php
-------- pages
----------- users.blade.php
-- web
----- views
-------- layout.blade.php
-------- pages
----------- users.blade.php
```

On `users.blade.php` I have `@extend('layout')` but the problem is that I can't specify which layout. Furthermore, I can't tell which users file should be load in controller. Is there any way to achieve that whitout using any prefix or suffix on the file and directory names?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `@extend('web.views.layout')` or `@extend('admin.views.layout')`

Comment: Thanks but, Laravel looks for view files in 'views' folder. So no way to set a parent folder name to `veiws`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register your view folder in the laravel AppServiceProvider file in the boot method:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/admin/views/', 'admin');
    }
```

And use it like the below:

```
return view("admin::pages.users")
```

Comment: Just like a package. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to use resource_path(): `$this->loadViewsFrom(resource_path('/admin/views/'), 'admin');`